# Clothing store access in Pokémon X & Y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Once the player obtains access to Lumiose City for the first time, they'll be able to visit Boutique Couture from the city's Vernal Avenue (South fork, connecting from South Boulevard). Upon entering the store without performing any other actions, the player will be turned away and informed they "aren't stylish enough" and that they should visit more places in Lumiose City before visiting again.

This description is dubious, and doesn't inform the player of what they need to accomplish to gain access. Specifically:

Even **beating the game** (completing the Pokémon League) fails to allow access, as does modifying the player's look, visiting most shops in all areas of Lumiose City, and performing all hair stylist, PR studio, and associated actions. Completing a set of triple battles in Restaurant Le Wow *did* set the event flag that allowed access in my copy of Y, but it is not clear if this is the only requirement for access.

So other players may benefit, and so I know how to repeat this process if I obtain a copy of X or the future release of Z, what exact requirements yield access to this store for the first time?

Comment: Just buy a crap tonne of Quick, Dusk and Timer Balls (150 or so balls) from the Poke Ball Emporium. You're going to use them anyway :)

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin Nice. I did this later, and received a big stylishness boost. When linked, http://www.pokemon-gl.com is also kind enough to unlock a badge associated this, marking each stylishness tier. Which is probably its own Guide Dang It, in a way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a picture from (what I think is) the official Pokemon X&Y Guide.

> Every little thing you do in Lumiose City adds to your style. Stylishness brings all kinds of rewards, such as meeting various characters, getting discounts, and unlocking facilities and fasions.

[image: listing some things that add to your style]

Good luck fellow trainers :)

Comment: For citation purposes: this is indeed from [*Pokémon X & Y: The Official Kalos Region Guidebook*](http://www.amazon.com/Pokemon-Official-Region-Guidebook-Strategy/dp/0804161992), p. 119, as confirmed by referencing my own copy.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I was shown the door at that Lumiose City clothes store for not being stylish enough, went to talk to Alexa about everything I could, then went back to the store and was suddenly considered "very stylish".

Answer (score 3):

The NPC outside the boutique says:

> Being stylish is about knowing *everything there is to know* about Lumiose!

This led me to believe that if you visit all of the main attractions, even if you don't do anything in them, you unlock the boutique. I used the connecting pathways to get through them all systematically, but I suppose the taxi service would work too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (although arguably lame and kind of "cheaty") and probably cheapest way is to **buy a bunch of Premier Balls**.
Make sure you buy them one by one. It is not necessary to exit the store or the buy dialog, you can simply select the Premier Ball and mash A.

I personally needed roughly 120 Premier Balls to unlock max style (which can be checked, among others, by trying to buy a Mega Stone in the Stone emporium; if you have max style, the price will be 10.000), but I did some style-raising actions before that, so I assume **150 should do if you start at 0 style**.
Don't believe the reports on the Internet which say you need 100. They're based on wrong observations because the people trying it had done more things to raise their style before starting to buy Premier Balls.

Note that Premier Balls only become available after you beat a few gyms (I believe it's 4, but I'm not sure). This will also work with **any other item**, but Premier Balls are the cheapest and at the same time most useful ones. I believe you have to buy from a Lumiose exclusive shop though, **the PokeCenter mart won't do**.

Answer (score 0):

I visited a few places and tried them out. Had nothing to do with the clothes. I was wearing the original outfit with a different hat.

Since she said I hadn't done enough around the city I just went in a circle and did a few things I saw and came back. Then she let me in. I doubt it's anything specific. You just have to do what the city has to offer.

Answer (score -1):

When you reach the town with the 7th gym leader, go to the clothes store and buy fancy-looking clothes.  I bought a frilly dress for my character with some knee socks and shoes, and got in easy.  The clothes in Lumiose City store go up to 200,000 poké, though.

Comment: This did not work. Specifically, I purchased clothing from most of the shops in the game, and did not receive access. After the restaurant sequence, without changing clothes whatsoever, I was granted access. (And happen to be rocking a suave fedora and red plaid jacket. :))

Comment: I managed to be stylish enough after the 5th gym (Maybe even before it so not it)

Answer (score -1):

You have to complete:

- Three jobs in the hotel at the North end of town
- Battle at both the one star and two star resturants.

There are also some theories about battling everyone in the alleys and the like, but I don't know if this is confirmed. I know the three restaurant jobs, however, as that was the final task that unlocked it for me.

Answer (score -1):

All I did was:

- Style my Furfrou
- 3 jobs at the hotel
- both restaurants (Le Nah and Le Yeah).

That was enough for me to access the boutique.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got in after experimenting with hairstyles for a while, but there just doesn't seem to be one specific trigger, as it seems to have been different things for everyone. Maybe it's random, maybe there's like a list of things and you have to do x of them to get in (someone on Serebii suggested this), or maybe what you have to do is somehow based on your ID No? Who knows ... :)

Answer (score -1):

It isn't related to what you are wearing or your hairstyle, I got in with the base set you get at the start of the game.

Just complete:

- 3 jobs at the hotel
- battle all courses at Restaurant le Nah/le Yeah.

Be warned, the clothes are a bit expensive, but are really cool! (Well, most of them)

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is work at the hotel and do all three jobs.  I got straight in.  I didn't battle, and I have normal clothes on.

Answer (score -2):

I visited every building in Lumiose, and defeated the battles at Le Nah. That's all it took for me. I never beat the Gym Leader.

Answer (score -2):

I styled my hair 20 times. Yeap. 20. I was trying really hard to get the Pigtails and Ponytail hairstyle which I heard needs repeated visits. After getting my hairstyle, I went in just for fun and got in ^^

Comment: Oh yeah, I have never gotten a part time job at the hotel before. So i don't think that helps. I have not visited all shops too. Good luck~